# Algolia instantsearch.js: how to get all facets

Tags: javascript, algolia, facet, instantsearch.js

I'm using instantsearch.js v4 and I'm trying to get a list of all facets configured in a index. (the ones defined in the Algolia dashboard)

There's a way to do that?

I'm not trying to get

```
 - Color:
   - green
   - red
   - ...
```

But what i'd like to get is:

```
 - Color
 - Size
 - (all the other facets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a list of all facets and record counts by passing the API a wildcard:

```
index.search('', {
  facets: ['*']
});
```

The list of facets and record counts will be in `facet_stats`

Docs:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/#retrieving-facets